# Using canvas on zoomed html body

Tags: html, css, canvas, zooming

I'm using the CSS style zoom for my HTML body.

```
body {
  zoom: 80%;
}
```

And my `canvas` can't handle the coordinates of the pen. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-z2wWKVQHaWm7LtqizM911ErFd8slYf/view

You can see this video to understand what I mean. The mouse and the click handler have a different position. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the function that detects the mouse position. In this moment you may have something like this:

```js
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
          var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          return {
            x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
            y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
          }
        }
```

You may want to change it to something like this:

```js
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
          var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          return {
            x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left)*scale_x,
            y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)*scale_y
          }
        }
```

In your case `scale_x = scale_y = .8`